# Trivial Problem: Sum of 2 bilinear forms is also a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

I've just been introduced to the concept of a bilinear form, and I'm having trouble understanding how addition is defined with 2 bilinear forms, which a question in a textbook asks:

Show the sum of 2 bilinear forms is also a bilinear form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bilinear form is just a type of function. Therefore, addition of bilinear forms is just regular function addition: pointwise addition.

If $f, g$ are bilinear forms then

$$(f+g)(v, u) = f(v, u) + g(v, u)$$

Comment: Might be clearer to write $(f+g)(x,y) = f(x,y) + g(x,y)$.

Comment: @Batman agreed, thanks for pointing that out; edited accordingly

Comment: probably worth adding that, in finite dimension  with chosen basis, we are just adding matrices; not necessarily symmetric if the form is not.

Answer (score 2):

For every $f,g: E\times F\to \mathbb{K}$ bilinear forms, for all $\lambda,\mu\in \mathbb{K},$ for all $x,y\in E$ and for all $z\in F$  $$(f+g)\left(\lambda x+\mu y,z\right)=f\left(\lambda x+\mu y,z\right)+g\left(\lambda x+\mu y,z\right)$$$$=\lambda f(x,z)+\mu f(y,z)+\lambda g(x,z)+\mu g(y,z)$$$$=\lambda \left(f(x,z)+g(x,z)\right)+\mu\left(f(y,z)+g(y,z)\right)$$$$=\lambda \left(f+g\right)(x,z)+\mu \left(f+g\right)(y,z).$$ In the same way, for all $\lambda,\mu\in \mathbb{K},$ for all $x\in E$ and for all $y,z\in F$ : $$(f+g)\left(x,\lambda y+\mu z\right)=\ldots=\lambda \left(f+g\right)(x,y)+\mu \left(f+g\right)(x,z).$$
So, $f+g: E\times F\to \mathbb{K}$ is a bilinear form.